# How to open 7z self extracting .exe file programmatically in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open the .exe file in button click. Using ZipFile.ExtractDirectory not working for .exe file and it throws exception.

Can anyone help me how to overcome this?

Comment: What exception?

Comment: UnauthorizedAccessException

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider using the LZMA SDK from 7-Zip [link](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) it contains the binaries, libraries and code examples on how to use properly the sdk with C# and other langs, it's like if you are using your owm 7-zip archiver. But only using all of you need.

Or, things more easier... [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27148/C-NET-Interface-for-Zip-Archive-DLLs)

Contains built-in compression/descompression modules only for implement in your solution.

Last thing, use the CLI of 7-Zip.

PD: Remember the UnauthorizedAccessException is due the Windows permission to your app, make sure you are reading/writting in a reachable directory, even you can add Admin Privilegies to your app. Hope this help you. Have a Nice Day! :)